# How to install R-devel on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, r-4.0, r-devel

I want to install R 4.0 for the newest Bioconductor submission. However, I cannot find instruction about the installation of R-devel for Mac OS, only the lists of prerequisites.

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#macOS

Is there something I'm missing?

All help, including breaking down the task into smaller steps that can be mastered individually, are welcome.

Comment: I am actually, trying to do exactly the same right now. I guess the tar should be located at https://mac.r-project.org/ but the devel version seems to be 3.6.3. (I was following the instructions for RSwitch https://rud.is/rswitch/guide/#basiccore_usage)

Comment: I asked on the R Mac special interested group mailing list and was told that at the moment the 4.0.0 build is broken (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2020-March/013271.html). However, after the build works again, I think the right procedure for installing the R-devel version is to follow the instructions from RSwitch https://rud.is/rswitch/guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Of this morning (26th of March 2020) the R 4.0.0 build is fixed and you can download the R-devel tar.gz from https://mac.r-project.org/

For the installation, I recommend following along the guide from RSwitch (https://rud.is/rswitch/guide/index.html).

1. Download the latest R-devel build:

```sh
wget https://mac.r-project.org/el-capitan/R-devel/R-devel-el-capitan-sa-x86_64.tar.gz
```

2. Unpack it at the root of your file system

```sh
sudo tar fvxz R-devel-el-capitan-sa-x86_64.tar.gz -C /
```

3. Open a new terminal and check if the installation was successful

```sh
~$ R --version
R Under development (unstable) (2020-03-25 r78063) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
```

The nickname "Unsuffered Consequences" indicates that the installation was succesful.